# How to use regex in awk for this case?

Tags: regex, awk

I am doing a scan over networks using nmap.

Results going to be below:

```
Nmap scan report for 30.142.41.52
Host is up.

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8080/tcp open http-proxy

Nmap scan report for 51.136.230.94
Host is up.

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8080/tcp filtered http-proxy

Nmap scan report for 58.188.208.42
Host is up.

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8080/tcp filtered http-proxy
```

I just wonder how to use grep or awk, to save only the State "open" results and save it in a text file?

I've tried something like...

```
awk '{print $5}' | sort -n > IPs
```

But it saves only the IP, so how to use regex in awk to save IPs with OPEN state?

Thank you in advance,
regards.
//terrisa

Comment: Please share your desired results for this sample `nmap` you have shared. This way we can know exactly how to write the awk to match your expectations.

Comment: @JNevill nmap -n -Pn -p T:80 -T5 -iR 10 | awk '{print $5}'

Comment: I apologize. What I'm hoping to get is how you want this to look after awk gets its hands on it. Are you just wanting it to spit out the IP if port 80 is open, or do you want it to print the IP and some other data if 80 is open? What would that output look like.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^Nmap/{ip=$5}; / open /{print ip}' file
```

or

```
awk '$1=="Nmap"{ip=$5}; $2=="open"{print ip}' file
```

Output:

```
30.142.41.52
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk you can set the Record Separator (RS) with the string of your choice, same thing for the Field Separator (FS):

```
awk -F"\n" -v RS='Nmap scan report for ' '$5~/ open /{print $1}'
```

This way, instead of working line by line, awk works block by block (from each 'Nmap scan report for ' until the next); and the Field Separator is a newline (that means that the first field is the IP and the fifth field is the line `8080/tcp open http-proxy`).

Note that if you use gawk, you can store each IP in an array and use the [asort](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html) function instead of piping the result to `sort`.

Comment: You should mention that only GNU awk allows multi-char RS strings.